# How to change Eclipse project folder structure to Maven/Gradle structure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I have created a Java project using Eclipse. Since I didn't do anything special, its folder structure is the default one that all Eclipse projects use:

```
Project
└── src
    ├── foo
    │   └── MyClass.java
    └── fooTests
         └── MyTest.java
```

However, I would like to migrate this to the folder structure [used by Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and derivatives such as Gradle.

```
Project
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── foo
    │       └── MyClass.java
    └── test
        └── foo
            └── MyTest.java
```

However, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to change my folder structure. The big issue seems to be what to do with the source folder. I tried to do this manually, but it tried to make the package for MyClass.java as `main.foo`, which I obviously don't want. I haven't found a maven or gradle plugin that converts the structure automatically.

How do I go about changing my Eclipse project folder structure to a Maven/Gradle structure?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can actually do all of this manually with minimal fuss.

1. In the Package Explorer view, right-click on your `src` folder and choose "Build Path" -> "Remove from Build Path"
2. Underneath the `src` folder, create a `main/java` folder
3. Right-click on the `main/java` folder and choose "Build Path" -> "Use as Source Folder"
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for `test/java`
5. Using the Eclipse refactoring tools (right-click on a folder or file and choose "Refactor" -> "Move…", move your Java files to the new folders

Once you're done with the refactoring, your project will be structured in the Maven way. This will make things much simpler when you decide to actually start using Gradle and Maven for your project.

Note that Java will still display your `src/main` folder separately in the project viewer. This is normal. Eclipse shows your source folder at top and then all other folders in the project view, which include the source folder parents.

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse does this for you if you have the maven and gradle pluging installed. Right click the project name, got to bottom of list, select configure and in there will be 2 options, 1 to convert to maven project and 1 to convert to gradle project. It handles the resetting of the source, etc.

Comment: Which Gradle plugin are you using for this? I don't see the option using Buildship, the official Gradle plugin.

Comment: use this url in your eclipse market place http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0?mpc=true&mpc_state=